# $f(\bar{A})= \overline{f(A)} $ implies $f^{-1}(F)$ to be closed proof

Tags: general-topology

> $X,Y$ are topological spaces $f:X\to Y$.
>
> 1)$\forall A\subset X$,$f(\bar{A})= \overline{f(A)} $
>
> 2)$\forall F$ closed in $Y\implies f^{-1}(F)$ of $X$ is closed.
>
> Prove 1) implies 2)

I know that a closed interval like $F=\bar{F}$ but I am not seeing how I can use the equality $f(\bar{A})= \overline{f(A)} $ to prove the relation. $\overline{f(A)}$ is does not necessarily imply A to be closed.

**Question**:

Can someone provide me a proof?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $F\subset Y$ is closed, and note that it suffices to prove that $\overline{f^{-1}(F)} = f^{-1}(F)$.  By hypothesis, we have
\begin{align*}
f\bigg(\overline{f^{-1}(F)}\bigg) &= \overline{f(f^{-1}(F))} \subset \overline F = F,
\end{align*}
where the last equality uses the fact that $F$ is closed in $Y$. Hence $\overline{f^{-1}(F)} \subset f^{-1}(F)$. On the other hand, by definition of closure, $f^{-1}(F)$ is contained in $\overline{f^{-1}(F)}$. Hence the claim.